Is this a good design for connecting 2 power sources to the PCB?
I’m designing a PCB that is powered by a 3-cell LiPo battery. The battery’s +12V output is stepped down to +5V using an LM2596S-5 switching regulator, and then further stepped down to +3.3V with an LP38693SD-3.3 LDO.
When programming the MCU, I want to power the PCB via a USB Type-C connection instead of using the battery. This would allow me to program the firmware without needing to connect or recharge the battery each time.
At the input of the LDO, I want to seamlessly switch between USB power, battery power, or both being connected simultaneously, without causing any conflicts. To achieve this, I’ve used two RB058L-30DDTE25 Schottky diodes. These diodes have:
Forward voltage: 680mV (I assume at 3A),
Forward current rating: 3A,
Repetitive reverse voltage: 30V,
Reverse current: 2.5µA.
Since the LP38693SD-3.3 LDO has a dropout voltage of approximately 250mV, I need a minimum input voltage of +3.55V to maintain regulation. With the maximum 680mV forward voltage drop across the Schottky diodes, the design ensures I still have sufficient input voltage, so this configuration should work well.
However, I have two concerns about the design:
VBUS Capacitance Compliance:
If a Schottky diode is placed between the buck regulator and its external circuitry, and the USB port (VBUS), does C14 (330µF) still count as capacitance on the VBUS line? My understanding is that the capacitance on the VBUS line must not exceed 10µF, and if C14 is counted, it would far exceed this limit.
Reverse Leakage Current from Diodes:
The diodes on the +5V and VBUS lines have a reverse current of 2.5µA. Could this small reverse current cause damage to any part of the circuit? Additionally, if both the battery and USB are connected simultaneously, could this reverse current damage the USB host (e.g., the computer)?
The power circuit:


Are you using 5 V for anything else in your circuit? If not, you could have your LM2596 do the step down to 3.3 V directly, remove U4 and have a P-FET switch on the input side of U3 to select between USB or battery.

@winny Thank you for the help! I’m using the +5V line because I also have three 90g servo motors. However, your recommendation to use a P-FET is excellent!

VBUS Capacitance Compliance
You can effectively consider VBUS to be an open circuit w.r.t. +5V as VBUS will never exceed +5V by VD5_fwd + VD4_rev = 30.68V.
Reverse Current from Diodes
As per the datasheet, the 2.5µA is not a leakage current; it is current when the diode is reverse-biased at VR = 30V.
Your approach, however, is not recommended. Switching between the power supplies should be used. A FET-based solution will have a lower power loss than forward biasing a diode due to the low RDS(on). You can also control the power sources to disconnect the battery buck converter circuit when USB-C is plugged in, which also addresses your two concerns.
There are ICs that implement this which is how I would recommend achieving this. Something like the TI TPS2121 seems suitable.

"A FET-based solution will have a lower power loss than forward biasing a diode" yes, but as it's feeding an LDO it just means the power will be lost there instead.

@HarryP Thank you very much for the help! I wasn't aware of this type of IC, but it seems like this one perfectly solves my problem.
